# jQuery Chosen move div content to another div

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I use the **jQuery Chosen** plug-in and I am trying to move the complete **Div Content** to another div when an user on a **checkbox** near it.

The problem is that, when I click on the checkbox, the divs are not rendered correctly, it looses the Chosen information and the result is just ugly.

The HTML I have:

```
Div A:<br />
<div id="divA">
</div>

Div B:<br />
<div id="divB">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkChosen" value="1" />&nbsp;
        <select data-placeholder="Testing" id="selectChosen" class="chzn-select" multiple="multiple" style="width:350px;">
            <option value="A">Option A</option>
            <option value="B">Option B</option>
            <option value="C">Option C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript code:

```
$("#selectChosen").chosen();

$('#chkChosen').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#divB div').hide().appendTo('#divA').fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $('#divA div').hide().appendTo('#divB').fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
```

I have created a jsFiddle with both a **working example** (normal select) and the **problem** (jQuery Chosen) : http://jsfiddle.net/Moonlight/fRHhh/1/

What is wrong? I thought that "appendTo" copies everything.

**EDIT**: I have created a new example of what I am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/Moonlight/fRHhh/5/

Answer (score 1):

I changed your jquery and now it works fine. Your where moving the created html by the plugin, instead of using the html to create a "chosen". After putting the html inside the correct container i call the .chosen again e voila.

```
 $("#selectChosen").chosen();

$('#chkChosen').live("change",function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#divB').html("");;
        $('#divA').hide().html('\
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="chkChosen" value="1" />&nbsp;\
         <select data-placeholder="Testing" id="selectChosen" class="chzn-select" multiple="multiple" style="width:350px;">\
            <option value="A">Option A</option>\
            <option value="B">Option B</option>\
            <option value="C">Option C</option>\
        </select>').fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $('#divA').html("");
        $('#divB').hide().html('\
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkChosen" value="1" />&nbsp;\
         <select data-placeholder="Testing" id="selectChosen" class="chzn-select" multiple="multiple" style="width:350px;">\
            <option value="A">Option A</option>\
            <option value="B">Option B</option>\
            <option value="C">Option C</option>\
        </select>').fadeIn('fast');         
    }

      $("#selectChosen").chosen();
});

$('#chkNormal').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#divD div').hide().appendTo('#divC').fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $('#divC div').hide().appendTo('#divD').fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: If I do that, I will loose what the user have selected. Also, if I have 3 chosens on that page, I will have to create 3 jQuery live statements? I was hoping to have a checkbox in front of a few Chosen statements, then move the ones that are selected.